# T8 LED Burn-in Process

Tags: led

[Direct Wire 4ft T8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B077YXVP8J) were purchased and installed.  Is there a rule of thumb or recommended process to burn-in the bulbs?

Is there a good test or process to weed out 'infant mortality?'

Answer (score 2):

Most modern lamps do not need a burn in period. You can just install them. As far as "infant mortality" I know of no field test other than install them and if you get a bad one it will usually burn out in 30 days or less. After that they shouldn't go bad for quite a while.

Comment: I agree, I have installed hundreds of direct wire lamps both t8 and t5. I have a few fail but the ones that did fail did so immediately or within a few minutes, I used to burn them in for an hour but now I just verify that all the lamps light I have had more problems with tombstones on older fixtures than anything else..

Comment: The takeaway is that burn-in is unnecessary and that infant mortality is within 30 days?